# FORTIFY_SOURCE: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE. Calling abort()

Tags: android

I'm a android programmer.

Today I run one android application that time I got this types of error.

> FORTIFY_SOURCE: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE. Calling abort().

so please if any one know this answer for this problem please reply me.

Comment: And how can we check the error without code?

Comment: By the way, if you're running into this issue it can be fixed by using the Google Play Services ProviderInstaller API. See this article for more information on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html

Answer (score 21):

Your process has too many file descriptor or sockets open, and when the OS limit is reached, your app gets killed.

**It is very unlikely that your app is legitimately using up all the resources, it is most likely a leak. You most probably miss a Close() call for a socket or a file resource.**

I met this issue on various Android devices with the same code. The most common error signature was:

```
01-27 15:50:52.431 I/DEBUG   (  172): pid: 12444, tid: 19014, oom: 0, name: DrmRequestHandl  >>> YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME <<<
01-27 15:50:52.431 I/DEBUG   (  172): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-27 15:50:52.517 I/DEBUG   (  172): Abort message: 'FORTIFY_SOURCE: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE. Calling abort().'
```

You can check the descriptor limit on your device calling:

```
adb shell ulimit -n
```

As a first step to solve the issue, you might need to figure out what kind of resources are leaking. You can figure out the process ID of your app by:

```
 adb shell ps
```

Then using the process ID, while your app is still running, you can check for open descriptors (you need root access or debuggable app/ROM):

```
adb shell ls -l  /proc/[YOUR_PROCESS_ID]/fd
```

For the process 12345 it would be something like:

```
adb shell ls -l  /proc/12345/fd
```

This will list the descriptors. On older android versions you can have 1024 items in the list, on Lollipop I saw 2048 as the default limit.

For **debuggable** app, you can use `run-as` (see @Joe 's comment):

```
adb shell run-as com.mycompany.myapplication ls -l /proc/12345/fd
```

Comment: You don't need root access to see the file descriptors:  `adb shell run-as $yourApplicationId ls -l /proc/$yourProcessId/fd/`.  E.g., `adb shell run-as com.mycompany.myapplication ls -l /proc/12345/fd`

Comment: I've written a simple shell script (tested on macOS) to monitor the number of open file descriptors for an Android app: https://gist.github.com/jhansche/322965fa3c3a6179114bc3ac8e4337ec

Comment: @Joe You are our saver, buddy, god bless you!!

Answer (score 0):

When I was testing my Vulkan renderer in "Intel x86 Atom_64" emulator, there were massive fd leaks named "anon_inode:sync_file".

Not sure it's related to this, but symptom was exactly same:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/1949

Anyway it never happened in Google APIs/Play emulator or in real device.

API level was 29, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to download several hunders of files at a time and meet the error.

You may check open descriptors with the following command (thanks, @Habib!)

```
adb shell ps
```

Find your application PID in the list and use another command (another thanks :)

```
adb shell run-as YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME ls -l  /proc/YOUR_PID/fd
```

I see about 150 open descriptors on a usual launch. And there are 700+ when files are downloading. Their number decreases only after some minutes, looks like Android frees them in the backgound, not when you can `close` on a stream.

The only working solution was use a custom ThreadPool to limit the concurrency. Here is the Kotlin code:

```
private val downloadDispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8).asCoroutineDispatcher()

private suspend fun downloadFile(sourceUrl: String, destPath: String, progressBlock: suspend (Long) -> Unit) = withContext(downloadDispatcher) {
    val url = URL(sourceUrl)
    url.openConnection().apply { connect() }
    url.openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(destPath)).use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            var bytesCopied = 0L
            while (bytesRead >= 0) {
                if (!coroutineContext.isActive) break
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                bytesCopied += bytesRead
                progressBlock(bytesCopied)
                bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```