# How increase FD_SETSIZE or limit the descriptor amount raised by Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to find a solution for this issue in Android Studio

```
Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 63080 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
```

I found someone facing kind of similar issue few years ago [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050913/4148175).

Basically it was argued:

> Your process has too many file descriptor or sockets open, and when the OS limit is reached, your app gets killed.
>
> It is very unlikely that your app is legitimately using up all the resources, it is most likely a leak. You most probably miss a Close() call for a socket or a file resource.

My issues isn't related to FortiFy like this one but the idea seems quite reasonable: somehow my application is missing a close somewhere. Well, I can't find where I forgot.

Here is the entire application:

```
package com.mycomp.appfirestore

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.mycomp.appfirestore.data.service.Endpoint
import com.mycomp.appfirestore.data.service.NetworkUtils
import com.mycomp.appfirestore.model.Posts
import com.mycomp.appfirestore.model.Transfer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import java.net.URL

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnTransfer=findViewById(R.id.btnTransfer) as Button
        val textViewTransfer=findViewById(R.id.textViewTransfer) as TextView
        btnTransfer.setOnClickListener {
            postTransfer()
        }
    }

    fun postTransfer() {
        val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils
            .getRetrofitInstance("http://192.168.15.13:8080/")

        val endpoint = retrofitClient.create(Endpoint::class.java)

        val transfer = Transfer("Demetrio","Jimis","100","","")
        val callback = endpoint.postTransfer(transfer)

        callback.enqueue(object : Callback<Transfer> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Transfer>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Transfer>, response: Response<Transfer>) {
                textViewTransfer.text = response.body().toString()
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Assuming there is no connection hold in my application here are  other useful info.

And my straight question is: is it possible either to increase FD_SETSIZE or limit the amount demanded by Emulator?

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.18363.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk>cd platform-tools

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86_arm model:AOSP_on_IA_Emulator device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:1


C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell ulimit -n
32768

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell ps
USER           PID  PPID     VSZ    RSS WCHAN            ADDR S NAME
root             1     0   17440   1812 0                   0 S init
root             2     0       0      0 0                   0 S [kthreadd]
root             3     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ksoftirqd/0]
root             5     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/0:0H]
root             7     2       0      0 0                   0 S [rcu_preempt]
root             8     2       0      0 0                   0 S [rcu_sched]
root             9     2       0      0 0                   0 S [rcu_bh]
root            10     2       0      0 0                   0 S [migration/0]
root            11     2       0      0 0                   0 S [migration/1]
root            12     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ksoftirqd/1]
root            14     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/1:0H]
root            16     2       0      0 0                   0 S [migration/2]
root            17     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ksoftirqd/2]
root            19     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/2:0H]
root            20     2       0      0 0                   0 S [migration/3]
root            21     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ksoftirqd/3]
root            23     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/3:0H]
root            24     2       0      0 0                   0 S [netns]
root            27     2       0      0 0                   0 S [perf]
root           383     2       0      0 0                   0 S [khungtaskd]
root           384     2       0      0 0                   0 S [writeback]
root           386     2       0      0 0                   0 S [crypto]
root           387     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           389     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kblockd]
root           502     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ata_sff]
root           522     2       0      0 0                   0 S [md]
root           533     2       0      0 0                   0 S [cfg80211]
root           649     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kswapd0]
root           650     2       0      0 0                   0 S [vmstat]
root           723     2       0      0 0                   0 S [fsnotify_mark]
root           790     2       0      0 0                   0 S [acpi_thermal_pm]
root           820     2       0      0 0                   0 S [hwrng]
root           826     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           827     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           828     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           830     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           831     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           832     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           833     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           834     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           835     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           836     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           837     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           838     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           839     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           840     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           841     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           842     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           876     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           879     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           882     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           885     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           887     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           891     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           894     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           897     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           900     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           905     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           908     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           911     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           914     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           918     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root           927     2       0      0 0                   0 S [iscsi_eh]
root           947     2       0      0 0                   0 S [scsi_eh_0]
root           948     2       0      0 0                   0 S [scsi_tmf_0]
root           949     2       0      0 0                   0 S [scsi_eh_1]
root           953     2       0      0 0                   0 S [scsi_tmf_1]
root          1031     2       0      0 0                   0 S [dm_bufio_cache]
root          1064     2       0      0 0                   0 S [binder]
root          1102     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ipv6_addrconf]
root          1125     2       0      0 0                   0 S [deferwq]
root          1138     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root          1143     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kdmflush]
root          1146     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root          1147     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kverityd]
root          1148     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root          1150     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ext4-rsv-conver]
root          1201     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ext4-rsv-conver]
root          1202     1    4484    376 0                   0 S init
root          1203     1    4228    380 0                   0 S init
root          1204     1    4868   1072 0                   0 S ueventd
root          1575     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/3:1H]
root          1579     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/1:1H]
root          1582     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/0:1H]
root          1584     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/2:1H]
logd          1587     1   20216   8444 0                   0 S logd
system        1589     1    7560   3328 0                   0 S servicemanager
system        1590     1   11496   4572 0                   0 S hwservicemanager
root          1594     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kauditd]
system        1595     1    8324   1880 0                   0 S vndservicemanager
system        1597     1   11676   3368 0                   0 S android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service
root          1598     1   19360   5328 0                   0 S vold
system        1639     1    8180   2296 0                   0 S android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service
root          1640     1    8548   3336 0                   0 S healthd
system        1641     1   17488   4068 0                   0 S vr_hwc
audioserver   1642     1   25744   4324 0                   0 S android.hardware.audio@2.0-service
audioserver   1643     1    9664   3028 0                   0 S android.hardware.broadmycompradio@1.1-service
cameraserver  1644     1   25680   4908 0                   0 S android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service
media         1645     1   11940   3012 0                   0 S android.hardware.cas@1.0-service
system        1646     1   12024   3160 0                   0 S android.hardware.configstore@1.1-service
media         1647     1   13568   3436 0                   0 S android.hardware.drm@1.0-service
media         1648     1   13464   3596 0                   0 S android.hardware.drm@1.1-service.clearkey
media         1649     1   16160   3192 0                   0 S android.hardware.drm@1.1-service.widevine
system        1650     1   11748   3092 0                   0 S android.hardware.gatekeeper@1.0-service
gps           1651     1   14208   3360 0                   0 S android.hardware.gnss@1.0-service
system        1652     1   26376   8736 0                   0 S android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service
system        1654     1    9444   2892 0                   0 S android.hardware.health@2.0-service.goldfish
system        1655     1    9180   3052 0                   0 S android.hardware.power@1.1-service.ranchu
system        1656     1   10908   3380 0                   0 S android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service
wifi          1657     1   13344   3844 0                   0 S android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service
root          1659     1    6992   1956 0                   0 S qemu-props
audioserver   1660     1   58964   7184 0                   0 S audioserver
root          1661     1    6248   2536 0                   0 S lmkd
system        1663     1   11212   3472 0                   0 S thermalserviced
logd          1664     1    7048   3136 0                   0 S logcat
root          1751     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kdmflush]
root          1752     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root          1753     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kcryptd_io]
root          1755     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kcryptd]
root          1756     2       0      0 0                   0 S [dmcrypt_write]
root          1758     2       0      0 0                   0 S [bioset]
root          1766     2       0      0 0                   0 S [jbd2/dm-1-8]
root          1767     2       0      0 0                   0 S [ext4-rsv-conver]
system        1773     1  122680  17548 0                   0 S surfaceflinger
root          1774     1 1328276  73156 0                   0 S zygote
cameraserver  1775     1   38124   6504 0                   0 S cameraserver
drm           1776     1   30592   6356 0                   0 S drmserver
incidentd     1777     1   12852   3696 0                   0 S incidentd
root          1778     1   15460   5004 0                   0 S installd
keystore      1779     1   16648   5712 0                   0 S keystore
media         1780     1   18408   4560 0                   0 S mediadrmserver
mediaex       1781     1   66496   9476 0                   0 S media.extractor
media         1782     1   28100   6596 0                   0 S media.metrics
media         1783     1   71932   9560 0                   0 S mediaserver
root          1784     1   31168   4460 0                   0 S netd
statsd        1785     1   15280   3728 0                   0 S statsd
root          1786     1   17680   4544 0                   0 S storaged
wifi          1787     1   13480   4848 0                   0 S wificond
mediacodec    1788     1   39960   6288 0                   0 S media.codec
radio         1789     1   17280   4016 0                   0 S rild
system        1791     1   13468   3668 0                   0 S gatekeeperd
tombstoned    1792     1    6180   2068 0                   0 S tombstoned
system        1794     1   10404   3232 0                   0 S android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service
system        1795     1   73348   9524 0                   0 S android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service
root          1820  1784    7204   3276 0                   0 S iptables-restore
root          1821  1784    7216   3416 0                   0 S ip6tables-restore
root          1849     1    6608    552 0                   0 S createns
root          1880     1    7212   1828 0                   0 S netmgr
root          1907     1    6620   2064 0                   0 S dhcpclient
root          1917     1    6876   2068 0                   0 S ipv6proxy
wifi          1920     1    9400   3508 0                   0 S hostapd_nohidl
root          1922     1    6748   1912 0                   0 S dhcpserver
system        1932  1774 1660764 194376 0                   0 S system_server
media_rw      2073  1598       0      0 0                   0 Z [sdcard]
u0_a26        2088  1774 1512096 132224 0                   0 S com.android.systemui
webview_zygote 2105 1774 1335148  38796 0                   0 S webview_zygote
wifi          2118     1   15512   2984 0                   0 S wpa_supplicant
radio         2186  1774 1456032  93200 0                   0 S com.android.phone
u0_a21        2473  1774 1411404  66936 0                   0 S com.google.android.ext.services
secure_element 2542 1774 1404016  59380 0                   0 S com.android.se
u0_a13        2655  1774 1423300  72612 0                   0 S com.google.process.gservices
u0_a61        2674  1774 1401668  58316 0                   0 S com.android.smspush
shell         2744     1   17712   1716 0                   0 R adbd
mdnsr         2751     1    2612    244 0                   0 S mdnsd
u0_a6         3658  1774 1481708 129256 0                   0 S com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
u0_a31        3794  1774 1443048  86176 0                   0 S com.google.android.ims
u0_a85        3908  1774 1448104  78408 0                   0 S com.google.android.apps.messaging:rcs
u0_a41        4549  1774 1484684  74116 0                   0 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor
u0_a72        6481  1774 1498964 136756 0                   0 S com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
u0_a13        6851  1774 1556300 182184 0                   0 S com.google.android.gms.persistent
u0_a13        6860  1774 1688152 188808 0                   0 S com.google.android.gms
u0_a13        7010  1774 1503160 143964 0                   0 S com.google.android.gms.unstable
u0_a41        7073  1774 1561792 181116 0                   0 S com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
root          7776     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/1:0]
u0_a79        8011  1774 1433232  92044 0                   0 S com.google.android.calendar
u0_a39        8025  1774 1406088  77008 0                   0 S com.android.providers.calendar
u0_a54        8062  1774 1416044  86508 0                   0 S com.google.android.deskclock
u0_a28        8095  1774 1423704  92412 0                   0 S com.google.android.setupwizard
root          8232     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/1:1]
root          8448     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/3:1]
root          8550     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/3:0]
root          8601     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/2:2]
root          8991     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/0:0]
u0_a5         9014  1774 1410536  82400 0                   0 S com.google.android.configupdater
u0_a15        9033  1774 1410736  89032 0                   0 S android.process.media
root          9193     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u9:2]
root          9235     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u9:4]
root          9481     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/2:1]
root          9541     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u8:2]
root          9598     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/0:2]
u0_a86        9642  1774 1475096 125504 0                   0 S com.mycomp.appfirestore
root          9826     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u8:0]
root          9887     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u8:1]
root          9888     2       0      0 0                   0 S [kworker/u9:0]
shell         9922  2744    7632   3004 0            f62fab39 R ps

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell ls -l  /proc/9642/fd
ls: /proc/9642/fd: Permission denied

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell run-as com.mycomp.appfirestore  ls -l  /proc/9642/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 1 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 10 -> /system/framework/core-libart.jar
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 11 -> /dev/binder
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 12 -> /system/framework/conscrypt.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 13 -> /system/framework/okhttp.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 14 -> /system/framework/bouncymycomple.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 15 -> /system/framework/apache-xml.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 16 -> /system/framework/ext.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 17 -> /system/framework/framework.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 18 -> /system/framework/telephony-common.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 19 -> /system/framework/voip-common.jar
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 2 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 20 -> /system/framework/ims-common.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 21 -> /system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 22 -> /system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 23 -> /system/framework/framework-oahl-backward-compatibility.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 24 -> /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 25 -> /system/framework/framework-res.apk
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 26 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 27 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 28 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 29 -> socket:[105880]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 3 -> socket:[105360]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 30 -> socket:[105881]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 31 -> socket:[105883]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 32 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 33 -> socket:[105368]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 34 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 35 -> /data/app/com.mycomp.appfirestore-epBvhJ1O_hVKuIJDOWoZ4Q==/base.apk
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 36 -> socket:[105368]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 37 -> socket:[105368]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 38 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 39 -> socket:[105881]
l-wx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 4 -> /dev/pmsg0
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 40 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 41 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 42 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 43 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 44 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 45 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 46 -> socket:[105957]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 47 -> socket:[105959]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 48 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 49 -> /data/app/com.mycomp.appfirestore-epBvhJ1O_hVKuIJDOWoZ4Q==/base.apk
l-wx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 5 -> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 50 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 51 -> socket:[106819]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 52 -> socket:[105961]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 53 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 54 -> /dev/hwbinder
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 55 -> /dev/goldfish_sync
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 56 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 58 -> socket:[107948]
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 6 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 61 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 04:39 62 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 63 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 64 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 65 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 66 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 68 -> /dev/ashmem
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 69 -> /dev/goldfish_pipe
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 7 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 8 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 u0_a86 u0_a86 64 2020-06-01 05:02 9 -> /system/framework/core-oj.jar

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>netstat -ano | findstr "5038"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5038         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6220
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5038         127.0.0.1:57691        ESTABLISHED     6220
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5038         127.0.0.1:57733        ESTABLISHED     6220
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5038         127.0.0.1:57767        ESTABLISHED     6220
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5038         127.0.0.1:57769        ESTABLISHED     6220
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57691        127.0.0.1:5038         ESTABLISHED     12920
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57733        127.0.0.1:5038         ESTABLISHED     12920
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57767        127.0.0.1:5038         ESTABLISHED     12920
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57769        127.0.0.1:5038         ESTABLISHED     12920

C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>netstat -ano | findstr "5037"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4944
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60754        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
```

... a lot lines delted with same TIME_WAIT for port 5037
      TCP    127.0.0.1:60909        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
      TCP    127.0.0.1:60911        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
      TCP    127.0.0.1:60916        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0

```
C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>
```

PS.: in case you wonder why I have port 5038 it is because I created an Environment variable named ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT with 5038

PS2.: I believe I added all relevant info above but if someone wish to see the whole project here is [repository](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/FireStoreDemos/tree/master/AppFirestore). It is really a small project with only a simple layout and the above Kotlin code.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a problem with the emulator itself and not with your project? Do you get the same error if you try to run a hello world project?

Comment: @somega I assume you are saying it because you don't get this error, right? May I ask you to share your emulator and Android Studio version with me? A bit funny question: do you use Windows 10 as me?

Comment: Other point, maybe the straigh answer to my question is "No, you can't increase FD_SETSIZE neither control its use"